# Why would you use Builder.Source() in a custom computation expression builder?

Tags: f#

Reading through the [F# 4.0 spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), I saw the following on page 79 of the PDF:

> The auxiliary function `src(e)` denotes `b.Source(e)` if the innermost ForEach is from the user code instead of generated by the translation, and a builder `b` contains a `Source` method. Otherwise, `src(e)` denotes `e`.

This is in the context of the spec's detailed (VERY detailed) description of how computation expressions are parsed and turned into a series of method calls on the expression's builder object. [Scott Wlaschin's Computation Expressions series](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html), which I found to be invaluable in helping me understand the rest of the concepts behind computation expressions, doesn't mention a `Source` method, nor does any other reference I've been able to find. (Google isn't much help with this one, as tons of people talk about source code and any references to `Source` methods gets buried).

I also don't see `Source` documented anywhere in the [MSDN page on computation expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx). The [QueryBuilder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323943.aspx) uses `Source`, so I have one example I can look at, but there's no explanation of why this would be useful in other circumstances.

Under what circumstances would you want to have a `Source` method on a custom computation expression builder? What would be a scenario where the default `ForEach` handling is inadequate to one's needs and a `Source` method would be useful?

Comment: @mydogisbox - Thanks for the link, but I saw that page earlier. I realize that `Source()` is being called with the contents of the `in` clause (i.e., `for item in x` produces a call to `Source(x)`). And I understand that `Source` should return something suitable to pass into the `For`. I don't quite see *why*, though. `QueryBuilder.Source` wants either an IEnumerable or an IQueryable (which inherits from IEnumerable), both of which are suitable for a `For` function to iterate over. So why is the `Source` call needed here? Why not just say "They gave me an IEnumerable, so I'll iterate over it"?

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing, I just didn't have enough room in a comment to explain what I meant. The `For` I'm talking about is `QueryBuilder.For`, which is called to handle the `for` expression in `query { **for** customer in db.Customers do select customer }`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not have any insider knowledge about this, but here is why I think the method exists, based on the translation and the implementation in built-in `QueryBuilder`.

All the operations in `QueryBuilder` represent the data source using `QuerySource<'R, 'Q>` where `'R` is the type of elements and `'Q` is the kind of data source - either `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.

The fact that there is just one data type means it does not need to define separate overloads for `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` - which would be otherwise needed because the `Run` method at the end needs to do different things for `IEnumerable` and for `IQueryable`.

So, the `Source` method lets you transform whatever inputs the query can work on into some "internal representation" of the data source. On the opposite end, the `Run` method turns the data from this internal representation into ordinary value. (In case of `QueryBuilder`, you never see the `QuerySource` type in your own code.)

Comment: "So, the `Source` method lets you transform whatever inputs the query can work on into some "internal representation" of the data source. On the opposite end, the `Run` method turns the data from this internal representation into ordinary value." -- This was the sentence that made it "click" for me. Thanks, that was the explanation that I needed.