# Why does this F# quotation fail at run-time?

Tags: f#, quotations

I am trying to understand why this F# script fails at run-time.

```ml
#r "nuget: FsToolkit.ErrorHandling, 2.2.0"

open System
open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

<@@ async {
        return!
          asyncResult {
            return! (Result.Ok true)
          }
} @@>
```

The error:

```sh
$ dotnet fsi ./Quotations.fsx

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not bind function AsyncResultBuilder.Source in type FsToolkit.ErrorHandling.AsyncResultCEExtensions
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.fail@1118[a](Type ty, String nm, Unit unitVar0) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1118
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.bindModuleFunctionWithCallSiteArgs$cont@1110(Type ty, String nm, Type[] argTypes, Type[] tyArgs, Unit unitVar) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1169
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.bindModuleFunctionWithCallSiteArgs(Type ty, String nm, FSharpList`1 argTypes, FSharpList`1 tyArgs) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1105
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_ModuleDefn@1572-1.Invoke(FSharpList`1 argTypes, FSharpList`1 tyargs) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1576
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_constSpec@1636.Invoke(FSharpList`1 argTypes, FSharpList`1 tyargs) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1636
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1492.Invoke(BindingEnv env) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1501
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1 cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:line 239
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:line 247
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1492.Invoke(BindingEnv env) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1493
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1508-2.Invoke(BindingEnv env) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\quotations.fs:line 1508
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1 cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:line 239
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:line 247
...
```

Is this an issue with F# quotations? Or the `FsToolkit.ErrorHandling` package?

Please explain the error message and why it occurs.

Answer (score 3):

As was stated by answer above, it possibly happens due to overload resolution in quotations. But you can work around that by wrapping builder in a function which is then passed to a quotation:

```
let returnResult =
  asyncResult {
    return! (Result.Ok true)
  }
      
let quotation =
  <@@
    async {
      return! returnResult
    }
  @@>
  
...
```

Here `returnResult` will be a `ValueOp` inside of `ValueWithName` returning the `returnResult` `FSharpFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is a combination of both. Here's what I've been able to determine:

- The F# compiler desugars your `asyncResult` expression into a call to `AsyncResultCEExtensions.Source`. See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286541/why-would-you-use-builder-source-in-a-custom-computation-expression-builder) and source code [here](https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/blob/master/src/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/AsyncResultCE.fs#L98).
- There are several different overloads of the `Source` method, so the quotation mechanism has some complicated logic to try to figure out which one to pick. See source code [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs#L1076).
- Unfortunately, the quotation mechanism can't figure out which `Source` method the compiler has in mind, so it fails with the error message you pasted: `Could not bind function AsyncResultBuilder.Source in type FsToolkit.ErrorHandling.AsyncResultCEExtensions`.

One might consider this a bug in the quotation mechanism, since it failed to understand the compiler's intent. However, I'm not sure if F# guarantees that every possible legal expression is quotable (hence the semi-friendly error message you encountered). Someone with more knowledge of the F# compiler and core library internals might be able to shine more light.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (notice I'm using `return` and not `return!`. I'm guessing that the type inference needs more information but I will not to investigate further.

```
<@@ async {
    return!
      asyncResult {
        return (Result.Ok true)
      }
} @@>
```

**Update**

After further investigation it appears there may be a bug. I opened a new issue [System.InvalidOperationException - Could not bind function *** in type](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11533)

The problem seems to be the computation expression library using a combination of things -

- Dividing builder overloads into separate modules
- Overloading the Source member (as mentioned in other answers)
- Using a weakly typed Result<bool, _> (the whole needs to be filled)
- Other Source member overloads that are not well typed i.e. Source (s:#seq<_>)
- Evaluation inside a quotation

Any change in one of these solves the problem.